# compare one column values with same column values of data in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[K_RT_GetRatebasedonmeat]
    @partyname int,
    @meattype int
AS 
BEGIN
   SELECT  
      CASE WHEN PE.meattype <> (SELECT meattype 
                                FROM K_RT_PartyNameYearly 
                                WHERE partyname = @partyname) THEN 0  
           ELSE ISNULL(PE.rateperkg, 0) 
      END AS rateperkg 
   FROM
      K_RT_PartyNameYearly PE
   INNER JOIN 
      K_RT_PartyName PN ON PE.partysno = PN.sno 
   WHERE
      PE.partysno = @partyname 
      AND PE.meattype = @meattype
END
```

out put:

```
PE.partysno    PE.meattype   PE.rateperkg
36             3             150
36             2             125 
25             2             100
```

if i pass partysno=36 and meattype=1 at that it will show 0 because there is no data for meattype 1 for that partysno

I wrote like this for my requirement but its not working properly. When I pass partyname and meattype as parameters, if `K_RT_PartyNameYearly` this table does not contain meattype for that partyname at that time I want to show 0 value. How can I write this? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS...

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[K_RT_GetRatebasedonmeat]
    @partysno int,
    @meattype int
AS 
BEGIN
 if  exists
( SELECT 1 FROM K_RT_PartyNameYearly WHERE partysno = @partysno AND meattype = @meattype)
BEGIN
   SELECT 
   PE.partysno ,
   PE.meattype,
    PE.rateperkg 
   FROM
      K_RT_PartyNameYearly PE
   WHERE
      PE.partysno = @partysno AND PE.meattype = @meattype
END
ELSE
BEGIN

   SELECT distinct
    partysno partysno ,
    null   meattype,
    0 AS rateperkg 
   FROM
      K_RT_PartyNameYearly PE
   WHERE
      PE.partysno = @partysno
END
END
```

Comment: It is givng two values

Comment: Giving two values means one is equal to @meattype and another is not equal to..right???

Comment: if table having meattype for that partyname it is giving rateperkg and zero if not it is giving two values as zero's

Comment: Can u provide PE,PN coloumns and sample data??